# PrestaShop working with Doctrine & Entites

Tags: doctrine, prestashop-1.7

Hello :) On start: I use PrestaShop 1.7.6.2 and MySQL 5.6 and PHP 7.2

I want to create a module on new way with Symfony Controller and Entites without ObjectModel (beacouse like say one of develoeper of PrestaShop: Pablo Borowicz - ObjectModel is deprecated)

So on start I create simple module available at the link
https://github.com/DarkSidePro/testmodule

Controller and routing works perfect the problem is when I try use enity manager

```
$entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$testRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(TestmoduleTest::class);
$test = $testRepository->findAll();
```

And I have error like that:

> The class 'DarkSide\Testmodule\Entity\TestmoduleTest' was not found in the chain configured namespaces PrestaShopBundle\Entity

Maybe I doing something wrong? But doc of prestashop of coures is suck about new way of creating a PrestaShop modules

Looking 4 help :) 
Thx all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrestaShop documentation is a completely mess concerning the handling of the Symfony repositories.

Doctrine is looking (by the `auto_mapping` orm configuration attribute) for the presence of your entity under the Prestashop `Entity` namespace, so given that your `TestmoduleTest` entity isn't there, it cannot be found and therefore loaded.

You may have to register [your entity](https://github.com/DarkSidePro/testmodule/blob/master/src/Entity/TestmoduleTest.php) under the following namespace : `namespace PrestaShop\Module\Testmodule\Entity;`

You'll be able to find more about how to create your own repository class inside the official `productcomments` module [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/productcomments).

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is on other way :) 
In this case i have problem with my Repository class (probably with constructor of this class) 
when I deleted them module start work 
Problem solved :)

Comment: If you do encounter an issue with your Repository class, please take a lookt at the [common.yml](https://github.com/PrestaShop/productcomments/blob/master/config/common.yml) file you have to create in a `config` subfolder of your module folder .